# Перенос элементов flexbox

Tags: html, css

Требуется, чтобы до переноса элемент занимал к примеру 50% ширины во flex-контейнере, а после уже 100%.
Подскажите, как это реализовать?

Comment: медиа запросом.

Comment: Что-то слишком кратно и непонятно чего нужно

Answer (score 1):

Для этих целей можно использовать `flex-wrap: wrap` для flex контейнера и свойство [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) (flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis) для flex-потомков.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}

.flex-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  flex: 1 0 45%; /*flex-basis должен позволять уместить 2 элемента в строку 
  с учетом отступов и бордера, для удобства можно сделать box-sizing: border-box*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```